# How to fetch all the results from MySQL table?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, angularjs

I am trying to fetch all the results from a phpadmin mysql table. The problem is that using the below code with php and angular JS, only the first row gets fetched everytime. Suppose there are 5 entries in the table. Whats happens is only the first one is getting displayed 5 times on the website. When i do an php echo (commented out in the code), it returns all the result from the table, but it is not working with angular JS.

I am also using  JS fuzzy search library which I have not provided here due to space issues. Here is the code otherwise :

```
</table>        
<?php

          $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user_files ORDER BY id DESC");  
          while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

          $id1 = $row['id'];
          $name = $row['user_file_name'];
          //echo $name.'<br/>';                     

?>

<div class="container" ng-init="books=[{book:'<?php echo $name;?>',author:'<?php echo $id1;?>'}]">
</div>                                


<tr ng-repeat="bookInfo in books | filter:bookText | orderBy:'book'">                                   


<td style="color: black;">{{ bookInfo.book }} - {{ bookInfo.author | lowercase}}</td>

<td style="color: black;" align="center">Size</td>
<td style="color: black;" align="center">Type</td>

<td style="color: black;" align="center" width=90%> 
<input type="button" name="read" value="Read"></td>

<td style="color: black;" align="center" width=90%>
<input type="button" name="write" value="Write"></td>

<td style="color: black;" align="center" width=90%>
<input type="button" name="download" value="Download"></td>

<td style="color: black;" align="center" width=90%>
<input type="button" name="share" value="Share"></td>

</tr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes because your initializing the array as

```
ng-init="books=[{book:'<?php echo $name;?>',author:'<?php echo $id1;?>'}]
```

after it compiles its showing something like

```
ng-init="books=[{book:'bookName1',author:'authorId1'}]
```

then there is only 1 book available for the `ng-repeat`

so what you have to do is,

```
<?php

  $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user_files ORDER BY id DESC");  
  $dataArr = array();         // to get the all the detail to a array
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
      $id1 = $row['id'];
      $name = $row['user_file_name'];
      array_push($dataArr , array("book"=>$name , "author"=>$id1));
  }
 ?>

... ng-init="books=<?php echo json_encode($dataArr); ?>">
```

Comment: I have tried it, its not working. Instead it does not show any files :(

Comment: I have kept the following 2 lines of code  intact                                                                  <tr ng-repeat="bookInfo in books | filter:bookText | orderBy:'book'">                                   

  <td style="color: black;">{{ bookInfo.book }} - {{ bookInfo.author | lowercase}}</td>
  </tr>

Comment: what do you see on inspect element  on `<tr ng-repeat="bookInfo in books | filter:b...`

Comment: I did an inspect element on the table definition and it shows all the files in the sql table, but they are not getting dislayed on the web. Here is the inspect element view                                                                  <div class="container" document.txt","author":"57"},{"book":"pic_bulboff.gif","author":"56"}]"="" text="" controller.html","author":"60"},{"book":"6cb58330","author":"59"},{"book":"fileread.txt","author":"58"},{"book":"new="" and="" view="" a="" book":"script.js","author":"61"},{"book":"creating="" ng-init="books=[{"> </div>

Comment: what u can see after `ng-init="books=` on inspect element ?

Comment: did you do what i suggest in the answer ? if yes what is echoing in line of `<?php echo json_encode($dataArr); ?>` ?

Comment: yes, thats what am saying. In the place of ng-init="books=<?php echo json_encode($dataArr); ?>",  this is showing under inspect element  :                                                                        ng-init="books=[{"

Comment: this is the inspect element status                                                                    <div class="container" document.txt","author":"57"},{"book":"pic_bulboff.gif","author":"56"}]"="" text="" controller.html","author":"60"},{"book":"6cb58330","author":"59"},{"book":"fileread.txt","author":"58"},{"book":"new="" and="" view="" a="" book":"script.js","author":"61"},{"book":"creating="" ng-init="books=[{"> </div>

Comment: ok then check `ng-init='books=<?php echo json_encode($dataArr); ?>'` this one. note the single quotes in `ng-init='`

Comment: Yep, worked, dont know why i didnt think of it in the first place. Thanks a ton man, its working now :)

Comment: aha glad to help you :) . please accept the answer and put a vote up :) thanks ;)

Answer (score 0):

Because your while loop is execution only 1 time, so you have to change the while loop logic.

Answer (score 0):

First of all create an array by fetching all the data from the table and convert it into json array. Note : Also define angular js controller "appController",

```
      <?php
        $books = array();
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user_files ORDER BY id DESC");  
        $i = 0;
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

          $books[$i]['id'] = $row['id'];
          $books[$i]['name'] = $row['user_file_name'];
          $books[$i]['bookText'] = $row['bookText'];
          $books[$i]['author'] = $row['author'];
          $i++;
        }

        $books = json_encode($books);
      ?>
```

Now assign this json array to the angular books array

```
      <script>
        function appController($data) {
          $data.books = "<?php echo $books; ?>" ;
        }
      </script>
```